# /usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory

Tags: docker

I am trying install Docker with Minetest thought Make. I download Dockerfile Makefile and supervisord.conf from here: https://github.com/zaoqi/minetest-novnc-docker
Use fromdos to convert them to Unix format.
And type 'make run' in ssh putty console.

Python was installed:

```
whereis python
python: /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3.6m /usr/lib/python3.7 /usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/lib/python3.6 /usr/lib/python3.8 /etc/python /etc/python2.7 /etc/python3.6 /usr/local/lib/python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python3.6 /usr/share/python /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz
```

This is what I get:

```
docker build -t minetest-novnc-docker .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  17.92kB
Step 1/18 : FROM ubuntu:rolling
 ---> 1e4467b07108
Step 2/18 : ENV HOME /root
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3407a6efb0a8
Step 3/18 : ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f3a0533ea69a
Step 4/18 : ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d7fd056a3c51
Step 5/18 : ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 934b4b9811c7
Step 6/18 : ENV LANGUAGE en_US.UTF-8
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 160a76a0f65b
Step 7/18 : RUN dpkg --add-architecture i386
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 57809f8a94e2
Step 8/18 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install xvfb x11vnc xdotool wget tar supervisor net-tools fluxbox
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 357d77a7dfcd
Step 9/18 : RUN apt-get -y install minetest
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 41ac99526ebb
Step 10/18 : ADD supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3e93cf58d6cb
Step 11/18 : ENV WINEPREFIX /root/prefix32
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6ca42cb2589e
Step 12/18 : ENV WINEARCH win32
 ---> Using cache
 ---> fd901c7b053b
Step 13/18 : ENV DISPLAY :0
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1b5a5e6bea09
Step 14/18 : WORKDIR /root/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d803b9b94520
Step 15/18 : RUN wget -O - https://github.com/novnc/noVNC/archive/v1.1.0.tar.gz | tar -xzv -C /root/ && mv /root/noVNC-1.1.0 /root/novnc && ln -s /root/novnc/vnc_lite.html /root/novnc/index.html
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 82c91196b4bb
Step 16/18 : RUN wget -O - https://github.com/novnc/websockify/archive/v0.8.0.tar.gz | tar -xzv -C /root/ && mv /root/websockify-0.8.0 /root/novnc/utils/websockify
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 265223c2766c
Step 17/18 : EXPOSE 8080
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a65d75d83457
Step 18/18 : CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a9fe960c3661
Successfully built a9fe960c3661
Successfully tagged minetest-novnc-docker:latest
docker run --rm -p 8080:8080 minetest-novnc-docker
2020-08-19 15:23:31,754 CRIT Supervisor is running as root.  Privileges were not dropped because no user is specified in the config file.  If you intend to run as root, you can set user=root in the config file to avoid this message.
2020-08-19 15:23:31,754 INFO Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf" during parsing
2020-08-19 15:23:31,758 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2020-08-19 15:23:31,758 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2020-08-19 15:23:31,759 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2020-08-19 15:23:32,761 INFO spawned: 'X11' with pid 7
2020-08-19 15:23:32,764 INFO spawned: 'app' with pid 8
2020-08-19 15:23:32,766 INFO spawned: 'fluxbox' with pid 9
2020-08-19 15:23:32,770 INFO spawned: 'novnc' with pid 10
2020-08-19 15:23:32,782 INFO spawned: 'x11vnc' with pid 11
Warning: Failed to open file(/usr/share/fluxbox/nls/C.UTF-8/fluxbox.cat)
for translation, using default messages.
###############################################################
#@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@#
#@                                                           @#
#@  **  WARNING  **  WARNING  **  WARNING  **  WARNING  **   @#
#@                                                           @#
#@        YOU ARE RUNNING X11VNC WITHOUT A PASSWORD!!        @#
#@                                                           @#
#@  This means anyone with network access to this computer   @#
#@  may be able to view and control your desktop.            @#
#@                                                           @#
#@ >>> If you did not mean to do this Press CTRL-C now!! <<< @#
#@                                                           @#
#@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@#
Warning: could not find self.pem
Using local websockify at /root/novnc/utils/websockify/run
Starting webserver and WebSockets proxy on port 8080
/usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4693:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4693:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4693:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5181:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackAlsa_open: Could not open playback device 'default': No such file or directory
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Audio: Global Initialization: Device Open
Failed to read: session.ignoreBorder
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.forcePseudoTransparency
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.colorsPerChannel
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.doubleClickInterval
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.tabPadding
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.styleOverlay
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.slitlistFile
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.appsFile
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.tabsAttachArea
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.cacheLife
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.cacheMax
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.autoRaiseDelay
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.ignoreBorder
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.forcePseudoTransparency
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.colorsPerChannel
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.doubleClickInterval
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.tabPadding
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.styleOverlay
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.slitlistFile
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.appsFile
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.tabsAttachArea
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.cacheLife
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.cacheMax
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.autoRaiseDelay
Setting default value
2020-08-19 15:23:33,169 INFO exited: app (terminated by SIGABRT (core dumped); not expected)
#@                                                           @#
#@  You can create an x11vnc password file by running:       @#
#@                                                           @#
#@       x11vnc -storepasswd password /path/to/passfile      @#
#@  or   x11vnc -storepasswd /path/to/passfile               @#
#@  or   x11vnc -storepasswd                                 @#
#@                                                           @#
#@  (the last one will use ~/.vnc/passwd)                    @#
#@                                                           @#
#@  and then starting x11vnc via:                            @#
#@                                                           @#
#@      x11vnc -rfbauth /path/to/passfile                    @#
#@                                                           @#
#@  an existing ~/.vnc/passwd file from another VNC          @#
#@  application will work fine too.                          @#
#@                                                           @#
#@  You can also use the -passwdfile or -passwd options.     @#
#@  (note -passwd is unsafe if local users are not trusted)  @#
#@                                                           @#
#@  Make sure any -rfbauth and -passwdfile password files    @#
#@  cannot be read by untrusted users.                       @#
#@                                                           @#
#@  Use x11vnc -usepw to automatically use your              @#
#@  ~/.vnc/passwd or ~/.vnc/passwdfile password files.       @#
#@  (and prompt you to create ~/.vnc/passwd if neither       @#
#@  file exists.)  Under -usepw, x11vnc will exit if it      @#
#@  cannot find a password to use.                           @#
#@                                                           @#
#@                                                           @#
#@  Even with a password, the subsequent VNC traffic is      @#
#@  sent in the clear.  Consider tunnelling via ssh(1):      @#
#@                                                           @#
#@    http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/#tunnelling            @#
#@                                                           @#
#@  Or using the x11vnc SSL options: -ssl and -stunnel       @#
#@                                                           @#
#@  Please Read the documentation for more info about        @#
#@  passwords, security, and encryption.                     @#
#@                                                           @#
#@    http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/faq.html#faq-passwd    @#
#@                                                           @#
#@  To disable this warning use the -nopw option, or put     @#
#@  'nopw' on a line in your ~/.x11vncrc file.               @#
#@                                                           @#
#@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@#
###############################################################
19/08/2020 15:23:33 x11vnc version: 0.9.16 lastmod: 2019-01-05  pid: 11
2020-08-19 15:23:33,835 INFO success: X11 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2020-08-19 15:23:33,835 INFO success: fluxbox entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2020-08-19 15:23:33,835 INFO success: novnc entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2020-08-19 15:23:33,836 INFO success: x11vnc entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
Failed to start WebSockets proxy

2020-08-19 15:23:33,861 INFO exited: novnc (exit status 1; not expected)
Failed to read: 2020-08-19 15:23:33,907 INFO spawned: 'novnc' with pid 25
session.screen0.opaqueMove
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.fullMaximization
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.maxIgnoreIncrement
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.maxDisableMove
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.maxDisableResize
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.workspacewarping
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.showwindowposition
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.autoRaise
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.clickRaises
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.defaultDeco
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.tab.placement
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.windowMenu
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.noFocusWhileTypingDelay
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.workspaces
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.edgeSnapThreshold
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.window.focus.alpha
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.window.unfocus.alpha
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.menu.alpha
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.menuDelay
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.tab.width
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.tooltipDelay
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.allowRemoteActions
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.clientMenu.usePixmap
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.tabs.usePixmap
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.tabs.maxOver
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.tabs.intitlebar
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.focusModel
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.tabFocusModel
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.focusNewWindows
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.focusSameHead
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.rowPlacementDirection
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.colPlacementDirection
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.windowPlacement
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.ignoreBorder
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.forcePseudoTransparency
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.colorsPerChannel
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.doubleClickInterval
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.tabPadding
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.styleOverlay
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.slitlistFile
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.appsFile
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.tabsAttachArea
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.cacheLife
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.cacheMax
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.autoRaiseDelay
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.opaqueMove
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.fullMaximization
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.maxIgnoreIncrement
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.maxDisableMove
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.maxDisableResize
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.workspacewarping
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.showwindowposition
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.autoRaise
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.clickRaises
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.defaultDeco
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.tab.placement
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.windowMenu
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.noFocusWhileTypingDelay
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.workspaces
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.edgeSnapThreshold
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.window.focus.alpha
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.window.unfocus.alpha
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.menu.alpha
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.menuDelay
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.tab.width
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.tooltipDelay
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.allowRemoteActions
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.clientMenu.usePixmap
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.tabs.usePixmap
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.tabs.maxOver
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.tabs.intitlebar
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.focusModel
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.tabFocusModel
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.focusNewWindows
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.focusSameHead
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.rowPlacementDirection
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.colPlacementDirection
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.windowPlacement
Setting default value
19/08/2020 15:23:33 Using X display :0
19/08/2020 15:23:33 rootwin: 0x388 reswin: 0x400001 dpy: 0x8307b0c0
19/08/2020 15:23:33
19/08/2020 15:23:33 ------------------ USEFUL INFORMATION ------------------
19/08/2020 15:23:33 X DAMAGE available on display, using it for polling hints.
19/08/2020 15:23:33   To disable this behavior use: '-noxdamage'
19/08/2020 15:23:33
19/08/2020 15:23:33   Most compositing window managers like 'compiz' or 'beryl'
19/08/2020 15:23:33   cause X DAMAGE to fail, and so you may not see any screen
19/08/2020 15:23:33   updates via VNC.  Either disable 'compiz' (recommended) or
19/08/2020 15:23:33   supply the x11vnc '-noxdamage' command line option.
19/08/2020 15:23:33
19/08/2020 15:23:33 Wireframing: -wireframe mode is in effect for window moves.
19/08/2020 15:23:33   If this yields undesired behavior (poor response, painting
19/08/2020 15:23:33   errors, etc) it may be disabled:
19/08/2020 15:23:33    - use '-nowf' to disable wireframing completely.
19/08/2020 15:23:33    - use '-nowcr' to disable the Copy Rectangle after the
19/08/2020 15:23:33      moved window is released in the new position.
19/08/2020 15:23:33   Also see the -help entry for tuning parameters.
19/08/2020 15:23:33   You can press 3 Alt_L's (Left "Alt" key) in a row to
19/08/2020 15:23:33   repaint the screen, also see the -fixscreen option for
19/08/2020 15:23:33   periodic repaints.
19/08/2020 15:23:33
19/08/2020 15:23:33 XFIXES available on display, resetting cursor mode
19/08/2020 15:23:33   to: '-cursor most'.
19/08/2020 15:23:33   to disable this behavior use: '-cursor arrow'
19/08/2020 15:23:33   or '-noxfixes'.
19/08/2020 15:23:33 using XFIXES for cursor drawing.
19/08/2020 15:23:33 GrabServer control via XTEST.
19/08/2020 15:23:33
19/08/2020 15:23:33 Scroll Detection: -scrollcopyrect mode is in effect to
19/08/2020 15:23:33   use RECORD extension to try to detect scrolling windows
19/08/2020 15:23:33   (induced by either user keystroke or mouse input).
19/08/2020 15:23:33   If this yields undesired behavior (poor response, painting
19/08/2020 15:23:33   errors, etc) it may be disabled via: '-noscr'
19/08/2020 15:23:33   Also see the -help entry for tuning parameters.
19/08/2020 15:23:33   You can press 3 Alt_L's (Left "Alt" key) in a row to
19/08/2020 15:23:33   repaint the screen, also see the -fixscreen option for
19/08/2020 15:23:33   periodic repaints.
19/08/2020 15:23:33
19/08/2020 15:23:33 XKEYBOARD: number of keysyms per keycode 7 is greater
19/08/2020 15:23:33   than 4 and 51 keysyms are mapped above 4.
19/08/2020 15:23:33   Automatically switching to -xkb mode.
19/08/2020 15:23:33   If this makes the key mapping worse you can
19/08/2020 15:23:33   disable it with the "-noxkb" option.
19/08/2020 15:23:33   Also, remember "-remap DEAD" for accenting characters.
19/08/2020 15:23:33
19/08/2020 15:23:33 X FBPM extension not supported.
Xlib:  extension "DPMS" missing on display ":0".
19/08/2020 15:23:33 X display is not capable of DPMS.
19/08/2020 15:23:33 --------------------------------------------------------
19/08/2020 15:23:33
19/08/2020 15:23:33 Default visual ID: 0x21
19/08/2020 15:23:33 Read initial data from X display into framebuffer.
19/08/2020 15:23:33 initialize_screen: fb_depth/fb_bpp/fb_Bpl 24/32/4096
19/08/2020 15:23:33
19/08/2020 15:23:33 X display :0 is 32bpp depth=24 true color
19/08/2020 15:23:33
19/08/2020 15:23:33 Autoprobing TCP port
19/08/2020 15:23:33 Autoprobing selected TCP port 5900
19/08/2020 15:23:33 Autoprobing TCP6 port
19/08/2020 15:23:33 Autoprobing selected TCP6 port 5900
19/08/2020 15:23:33 listen6: bind: Address already in use
19/08/2020 15:23:33 Not listening on IPv6 interface.
19/08/2020 15:23:33
19/08/2020 15:23:33 Xinerama is present and active (e.g. multi-head).
19/08/2020 15:23:33 Xinerama: number of sub-screens: 1
19/08/2020 15:23:33 Xinerama: no blackouts needed (only one sub-screen)
19/08/2020 15:23:33
19/08/2020 15:23:33 fb read rate: 680 MB/sec
19/08/2020 15:23:33 fast read: reset -wait  ms to: 10
19/08/2020 15:23:33 fast read: reset -defer ms to: 10
19/08/2020 15:23:33 The X server says there are 10 mouse buttons.
19/08/2020 15:23:33 screen setup finished.
19/08/2020 15:23:33
19/08/2020 15:23:33 WARNING: You are running x11vnc WITHOUT a password.  See
19/08/2020 15:23:33 WARNING: the warning message printed above for more info.
19/08/2020 15:23:33

The VNC desktop is:      5c2037d22477:0
PORT=5900

******************************************************************************
Have you tried the x11vnc '-ncache' VNC client-side pixel caching feature yet?

The scheme stores pixel data offscreen on the VNC viewer side for faster
retrieval.  It should work with any VNC viewer.  Try it by running:

    x11vnc -ncache 10 ...

One can also add -ncache_cr for smooth 'copyrect' window motion.
More info: http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/faq.html#faq-client-caching

Warning: could not find self.pem
Using local websockify at /root/novnc/utils/websockify/run
Starting webserver and WebSockets proxy on port 8080
/usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory
Failed to read: session.screen0.slit.acceptKdeDockapps
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.slit.autoHide
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.slit.maxOver
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.slit.placement
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.slit.alpha
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.slit.onhead
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.slit.layer
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.toolbar.autoHide
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.toolbar.maxOver
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.toolbar.visible
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.toolbar.alpha
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.toolbar.layer
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.toolbar.onhead
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.toolbar.placement
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.toolbar.height
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.iconbar.mode
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.iconbar.alignment
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.iconbar.iconWidth
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.iconbar.iconTextPadding
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.iconbar.usePixmap
Setting default value
Failed to start WebSockets proxy


2020-08-19 15:23:34,998 INFO spawned: 'app' with pid 44
2020-08-19 15:23:34,998 INFO success: novnc entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2020-08-19 15:23:34,999 INFO exited: novnc (exit status 1; not expected)
2020-08-19 15:23:35,001 INFO spawned: 'novnc' with pid 45
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4693:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4693:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4693:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5181:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackAlsa_open: Could not open playback device 'default': No such file or directory
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Audio: Global Initialization: Device Open
Warning: could not find self.pem
Using local websockify at /root/novnc/utils/websockify/run
Starting webserver and WebSockets proxy on port 8080
/usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory
2020-08-19 15:23:35,164 INFO exited: app (terminated by SIGABRT (core dumped); not expected)
Failed to start WebSockets proxy

2020-08-19 15:23:36,045 INFO success: novnc entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2020-08-19 15:23:36,045 INFO exited: novnc (exit status 1; not expected)
2020-08-19 15:23:37,048 INFO spawned: 'novnc' with pid 57
Warning: could not find self.pem
Using local websockify at /root/novnc/utils/websockify/run
Starting webserver and WebSockets proxy on port 8080
/usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory
Failed to start WebSockets proxy

2020-08-19 15:23:38,071 INFO spawned: 'app' with pid 68
2020-08-19 15:23:38,071 INFO success: novnc entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2020-08-19 15:23:38,072 INFO exited: novnc (exit status 1; not expected)
2020-08-19 15:23:38,074 INFO spawned: 'novnc' with pid 69
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4693:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4693:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4693:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5181:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackAlsa_open: Could not open playback device 'default': No such file or directory
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Audio: Global Initialization: Device Open
Warning: could not find self.pem
Using local websockify at /root/novnc/utils/websockify/run
Starting webserver and WebSockets proxy on port 8080
/usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory
2020-08-19 15:23:38,249 INFO exited: app (terminated by SIGABRT (core dumped); not expected)
Failed to start WebSockets proxy

2020-08-19 15:23:39,122 INFO success: novnc entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2020-08-19 15:23:39,123 INFO exited: novnc (exit status 1; not expected)
2020-08-19 15:23:39,125 INFO spawned: 'novnc' with pid 81
Warning: could not find self.pem
Using local websockify at /root/novnc/utils/websockify/run
Starting webserver and WebSockets proxy on port 8080
/usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory
^C^C^CFailed to start WebSockets proxy
```

Can you help me to fix it?